# Spring Rest API : Password encoding

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Project is built on Spring-4 and have beans for SMTP connection and MySql database. However these configurations are in XML files along with readable passwords. Is there any suggestions of not having readable passwords in Spring XML?

I tried searching through multiple blogs, sites but not found clear-cut answer, appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Why that matters when your xml configuration files are in a secure zone?

Comment: @Nguyen : I also want to understand this perspective, do you think WAR file on remote servers are secure enough? If someone gets access to it, things will be exposed. So just want to have additional layer of security.

Comment: JDBC connection details (for MySQL databases for example) can be moved to a JNDI datasource within the app server. App servers like JBoss typically encrypt JNDI object values so your JDBC connection details will be secure if they are configured as a JNDI datasource. SMTP connection details can similarly be stored as a JNDI resource. If you work with Tomcat, you may have to encrypt and decrypt JNDI resource details yourself.

Comment: @Manish - Thank you, do you know how can I do it in tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the encoded password in the configuration file and decoded the password in a custom `DataSource`. Following is the idea:

1.
Encode the password and put it into the configuration file:

You can use any algorithm to encode it or secure it with encryption. For example, use Base64 to encode a password of "myPassword" to "bXlQYXNzd29yZA==" and put into configuration file:

```
<property name="password"><value>bXlQYXNzd29yZA==</value></property>
```

2.
Implement a custom `DataSource` and decode/decrypt the password in the corresponding method. Following is an example which extends `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`:

```
public class CustomDataSource extends BasicDataSource{

    public void setPassword(String encodedPassword){
        this.password = decodePassword(encodedPassword);
    }

    private String decodePassword(String encodedPassword) {
        // decode or decrypt the encodedPassowrd 
        return decodedPassword;
    }
}
```

3.
Use the custom `DataSource` in your configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="CustomDataSource">
    <!-- other properties like driverClassName, url, username, etc. -->
    <property name="password"><value>bXlQYXNzd29yZA==</value></property>   
</bean>
```